# Ubuntu DVD ripping problem

Tags: dvd

After starting a DVD rip with K3b it does nothing and stays at 0% progress until I cancel it.  It doesn't report any problems.  There's a list of titles and languages for the audio.

### System

K3b Version: 2.0.3
KDE Version: 4.14.16
QT Version:  4.8.7
Kernel:      4.4.0-53-generic

### Used versions

transcode: 1.1.7

Thanks for any help.

Handbrake got it done, although I'd still like to understand why K3b would not.

Comment: Have you tried to start K3b from terminal and see if it outputs anything interesting there ?

Comment: QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
unnamed app(6576): KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken." 

unnamed app(6575): KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.

Comment: I don't have KDE installed, but it looks like some part of KDE isn't running correctly. We may hope that someone else here can dig deeper into the problem thaqn I can ;-)

Comment: why don't you post those error into your post.